# How can I read a file txt that is inside the project?

Tags: java, file, path

I want to make possible that any file inside my project can be readable by any user, considering that they wont have the same directory as me.

So i have this:

```
String filme = "somefile.txt"

String datastr = "";
   reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("C:/Path"+filename));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while( line != null) {
        datastr += line + "\n";
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914375/getting-file-path-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be simple, `ClassLoader` is answer:

```
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL rsc = cl.getResource("MyFile.txt");
File f = new File(rsc.getPath());
```

But here are more answers on this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914375/getting-file-path-in-java), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425002/get-path-of-a-file-in-java) just for quick search. Use search! ;-)

Comment: So i did it like this...

String datastr = "";

     ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
     URL rsc = cl.getResource(file);
     FileReader f = new FileReader(rsc.getPath());
     reader = new BufferedReader(f);

  String line = reader.readLine();
  while( line != null) {
   datastr += line + "\n";
   line = reader.readLine();
  }

and received the java.lang.NullPointerException...

Comment: @pmpc use debugger to find-out in which step you get NPE. and what is in your `file` variable?